# How can I print a LaTeX document with raster images in halftone?

Tags: graphics, printing

I have a LaTeX document with photos in it, and I would like to print this in high quality halftone on a black and white laser printer. I would like to achieve a better [halftone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halftone) than the one my printer driver does automatically for images sent to the printer.

Is there a way to apply a halftone-screen to the images in the pdf when I compile my LaTeX code?

Is there some other way to halftone the images in the resulting pdf document before sending it to the printer?

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, thanks for your suggestion, but I don't know how a MWE could help here since it's a question about the **possibility** to do a halftone. I now clarified that it's for black and white printing.

Comment: I suppose that should be a task for [ICC profiles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICC_profile) and your printer driver. Unfortunately that's more of a PDF/ICC subject and not so much a TeX-thing I think.

Comment: As commented, this really is a PDF thing. If you know exactly what you need to do in the PDF and want to know how to do it at the TeX level it might be on topic.